# how can i use ffmpeg h264 encoder as directshow filter

Tags: ffmpeg, directshow, h.264, mp4

i want to encode live stream video to h264 and generate mp4 file.
i am using directshow (graph)

how can i add ffmpeg's h264 encoder  as a directshow filter?

Thanks & Regards,
Vishal Parekh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ffmpeg` itslelf does not offer DirectShow interface for the implemented encoder. Hence, you need a `ffmpeg`-derived work, such as wrapper, instead. `ffdshow` and [`ffdshow tryouts`](http://ffdshow-tryout.sourceforge.net/) are the popular options, which you seem to have already discovered.

Comment: thanks Roman, i am going to try x264vfw